# Target each element of a while loop independently in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

My website consists of a big stream of pictures. Each of them is displayed dynamically using a `while` loop. I want to give users the ability to save the pictures they like to a personal collection. I have a button on each picture that triggers two javascript functions:

1. Toggle the text of the button from "Save" to "Unsave" and from "Unsave" to "Save"
2. Create or delete the corresponding record in the database

Here's the PHP (the `if (in_array($itemId, $saved)) {}` is there to show different buttons whether or not the picture's already saved).

```
<?php
    if (!in_array($itemId, $saved)) {
?>                                  
    <button class="item-save" id="save" type="button" value="<?php echo $itemId; ?>" onclick="saveSwitch(this.id); saveItem();">Save</button>

    <button class="item-save item-act-save-unsave-hide" id="unsave" type="button" value="<?php echo $itemId; ?>" onclick="saveSwitch(this.id); unsaveItem();">Unsave</button>
<?php
    } else {
?>
    <button class="item-save" id="unsave" type="button" value="<?php echo $itemId; ?>" onclick="saveSwitch(this.id); saveItem();">Unsave</button>

    <button class="item-save item-act-save-unsave-hide" id="save" type="button" value="<?php echo $itemId; ?>" onclick="saveSwitch(this.id); unsaveItem();">Save</button>
<?php
    }
?>
```

And the Javascript functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Switch between "Save" and "Unsave" buttons
function saveSwitch(id) {
    if(id == "save") {
        document.getElementById("unsave").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("save").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
    }
}

// save: creates new record in "saves" table
function saveItem() {
    var item_id = $("#save").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {"item_id": item_id},
        url: "save.php",
    });
}

// unsave: deletes existing record in "saves" table
function unsaveItem() {
    var item_id = $("#unsave").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {"item_id": item_id},
        url: "unsave.php",
    });
}
</script>
```

Everything works fine but the problem is that I target the elements (pictures) using their ID, therefore the different buttons, variables and values only affect the first picture.

I'm new to Javascript and I don't see how I should target each element independently. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about if you updated your generation code to pass a value to `saveItem`/`unsaveItem`:

```
<button class="item-save" id="save" type="button" value="<?php echo $itemId; ?>" 
    onclick="saveSwitch(this.id); saveItem(this.value);"
>Save</button>
```

and then updated those functions to accept that value as `itemId`, which you then wouldn't need to calculate?

(And note that Ricky Sett is right; you really shouldn't repeat IDs in markup.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean `saveItem(this.<?php echo $itemId; ?>)` and `function saveItem(id) { var item_id = id; $.ajax({ type: "POST", data: {"item_id": item_id}, url: "save.php", }); }` ?

Comment: No.  I'm not sure, but I think my change would be correct as written for the PHP.  And you could just write `function(item_id) { $.ajax /*...*/  }`.  Alternatively, you can create ids like `id="save-<?php echo $itemId; ?>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a class name to the pictures instead of an ID. In reality ID's should be unique and shouldn't repeat in a page.

```
$(".pictureClassName").each(function(){
    var picturevalue = $(this).val()
    --Do something with value
});
```

If you are targeting a specific image I would use the ID but I would make it unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see what to do with this... :-/ Where do I get "picturevalue" from for instance?

Comment: the example I added would loop through all the pictures you have. I may have misunderstood your question. After I read Scott's answer he's right. You can add an onclick handler to each button and pass the value to the function. It would make it much easier than looping through all images.